# Update OpenAI embedding based on own domain corpus

Tags: transformer, open-ai, word-embedding, embeddings, gpt-3

I have a large domain corpus. Is there anyway to update the word/sentence/document embedding obtained from OpenAI embedding API based on my own domain corpus? There may be some words in my corpus that are close to each other but far from each other in OpenAI embedding space.

Any tutorials or guidance will be helpful.